# How would I wrap a C API without exposing the C API?

Tags: c++, c

I'd like to wrap a C API into a set of C++ classes, but at the same time it would be preferable that the consumers of these classes not know anything about the API.

For example, wrapping Lua's C api attempt 1:

```
// State.hpp
#pragma once
struct lua_State;
class State {
private:
    lua_State *state;
public: 
    State();
    ~State();
    void runFile(char* name);
};
```

Then for the cpp file:

```
// State.cpp
#include "State.h"
#include "lua.hpp"
State::State() {
    state = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(state);
}
State::~State() {
    lua_close(state);
}
void State::runFile(char* name) {
    luaL_dofile(state, name);
}
```

This means that any file including State.hpp will see lua_State, which is undesirable. What I want is for any files including State.hpp to *not* see any portion of the C API including its structs, but I also don't want to use void* or something and cast to lua_State in every member function. I saw that [opaque pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) are one method to do what I want, but I don't see a way to define the private struct to be lua_State.

Comment: Are you amenable to the [pimpl idiom?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

Comment: If you want to avoid pimpl, try having a `namespace detail`, or any other namespace name that obviously means don't touch

Comment: Pimpl: would like to avoid having to use `m.state` or similar to access the state in member functions. Namespace: Do you mean to forward declare the lua_State struct in a wrapper-specific namespace or something else?

Comment: What you have in your first snippet **is** an opaque pointer. Any consumer will only know that there is a `struct` named `lua_State`, but nothing about what's inside the struct. If this isn't good enough, indeed, go for a pimpl.

Comment: Oh, ok. Will probably go with pimpl then. Thanks.

Comment: Start off by not using raw pointers. As written your code will break if someone copies a State object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way forward is to forward declare the item.

```
  struct lua_state;
```

That allows the user to see that something called a lua_state is used, but can't see the details.

### pimpl

forward declare a structure

```
struct hiddenData;
```

Use this structure in your class

```
class State {
private:
    hiddenData *state;
public: 
    State();
    ~State();
    void runFile(char* name);
};
```

In the cpp file.

```
// State.cpp

#include "State.h"
#include "lua.hpp"

struct hiddenData {
    lua_state * L;
    // for ease of use...
    hiddenData( lua_state * l ) : L(l) {}
}
State::State() {
    state = new hiddenData( luaL_newstate() );
    luaL_openlibs(state->L);
}
State::~State() {
    lua_close(state->L);
}
void State::runFile(char* name) {
    luaL_dofile(state->L, name);
}
```